# ALTER INDEX failed because of QUOTED_IDENTIFIER when running from sp_msForEachTable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, reindex, sp-msforeachtable

When I try to rebuild an index on a table:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[Allocations] REBUILD
```

that works fine.

But when I call

```
EXECUTE sp_msForEachTable 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD'
```

I reach the same same table, and it fails with:

> Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   ALTER INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

---

And to confirm that it's the same table:

```
EXECUTE sp_msForEachTable 'print ''Rebuilding ?'';
ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD;
PRINT ''   Done ?'''
```

which gives the results:

```
Rebuilding [dbo].[SystemConfiguration]
   Done [dbo].[SystemConfiguration]
Rebuilding [dbo].[UserGroups]
   Done [dbo].[UserGroups]
Rebuilding [dbo].[Groups]
   Done [dbo].[Groups]
Rebuilding [dbo].[UserPermissions]
   Done [dbo].[UserPermissions]
Rebuilding [dbo].[AllocationAdmins]
   Done [dbo].[AllocationAdmins]
Rebuilding [dbo].[Allocations]
Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
ALTER INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.
```

What am I not doing wrong?

---

**Note**:

```
EXECUTE sp_msForEachTable 'DBCC DBREINDEX(''?'')'
```

works ***fine!***

Comment: "What am i not doing wrong?" - there could be a large number of answers to that question :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Quoted identifier settings are stored against each stored procedure, and `sp_MSforeachtable` has it defined as `OFF`. However, you can work around this - by setting it to `ON` before it executes the re-index:

```
create table dbo.T (
    ID int not null,
    constraint PK_T PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
go
create view dbo.V ( ID)
with schemabinding
as
    select ID from dbo.T
go
create unique clustered index IX_V on dbo.V(ID)
go
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.V REBUILD --Fine
go
exec sp_MSforeachtable  'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD' --Errors
go
exec sp_MSforeachtable  'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD' --Fine
```

---

[`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx):

> When a stored procedure is created, the `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` and `SET ANSI_NULLS` settings are captured and used for subsequent invocations of that stored procedure.

---

And, of course, insert the usual caveats about `sp_MSforeachtable` being undocumented, and so you can't rely on any of its behaviour being stable.

---

For [`DBCC DBREINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181671.aspx) - all bets are off. `DBCC` lives in its own little, very customized code world. But, of course, it shouldn't be relied on for future work either:

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. Use [`ALTER INDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx) instead.

Comment: That's how i discovered the "bug" when using `ALTER INDEX`; i was using `DBCC` just fine, and thought i would make my life more miserable by switching to the "preferred" syntax.

Answer (score 10):

You need the `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` in the `sp_msForEachTable` as well, because `sp_msForEachTable` does not have the right setting.

```
EXECUTE sp_msForEachTable 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD;'
```

Comment: If the session defaults didn't have the right setting, you might expect that the direct `ALTER INDEX` call would also fail.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use sp_msforeachtable. It has been documented to miss object. You would be much better off iterating through a list of tables using sys.tables.

```
DECLARE @id INT ,
    @table NVARCHAR(256) ,
    @reindex NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT  @id = MIN(object_id)
FROM    sys.tables
WHILE @id IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @table = QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
        FROM    sys.tables t
                INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
        WHERE   t.object_id = @id

        SELECT  @reindex = 'SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER ON; ALTER INDEX ALL ON '
                + @table + ' REBUILD;'
        PRINT @reindex --prints the reindex command
        --EXEC @reindex --uncomment to actually reindex

        SELECT  @id = MIN(object_id)
        FROM    sys.tables
        WHERE   object_id > @id
   END
```

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ForEachTable @query varchar(8000) AS

  --todo
```

Comment: It would be cooler if you gave the sql to create an equivalent `sp_forEachTable`, and infinitely more useful. i would then whore it around to every database i touch.

Comment: That really is an equivalent. You could turn that into a stored procedure, add the database name & command as parameters, then just call it whenever you need it.

Comment: On the downside: i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Missing underscore in code example:

**WAS**

```
ELECT  @reindex = 'SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER ON; ALTER INDEX ALL ON '
                + @table + ' REBUILD;'
```

**IS**

```
ELECT  @reindex = 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; ALTER INDEX ALL ON '
                + @table + ' REBUILD;'
```