# Use of QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to overcome 'ALTER INDEX failed' error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Like [others previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674664/alter-index-failed-because-of-quoted-identifier-when-running-from-sp-msforeachta), today in my SQL logs I can see that a scheduled job has failed to execute due to Error 1934.

> ALTER INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'

After reading [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic150354-5-1.aspx), [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/06/07/sql-server-quoted_identifier-onoff-explanation-and-example-question-on-real-world-usage/) and [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/07/sql-statistics/statistics-updates), I still feel unsure about whether my *hack* (below) is introducing risk based upon advice given elsewhere.  My lack of experience is the main driver for this question.

The original code is:

```
DECLARE @Database varchar(255);
DECLARE @Table varchar(255);
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @fillfactor int = 90;

DECLARE DatabaseCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    name
FROM
    MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE
    name IN ('MyDbName')
ORDER BY
    name;

OPEN DatabaseCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @cmd = 'DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ''['' + table_catalog + ''].['' + table_schema + ''].['' +
      table_name + '']'' as tableName FROM ' + @Database + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
      WHERE table_type = ''BASE TABLE''';

        -- create table cursor  
        EXEC (@cmd);
        OPEN TableCursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table;
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
            BEGIN
                SET @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @Table + ' REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = ' + CONVERT(varchar(3), @fillfactor) + ')';

                EXEC (@cmd);
                FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table;
            END

        CLOSE TableCursor;
        DEALLOCATE TableCursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database;
    END
CLOSE DatabaseCursor;
DEALLOCATE DatabaseCursor;

USE MyDbName;
GO
EXEC sys.sp_updatestats;
```

I believe that this error began occuring after an index was added to an XML column in one particular table, but I'm not 100% sure. Elsewhere we also have stored procedures that use XPATH. I know others have experienced the same error, but without the experience of manually setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, I'm looking for advice plus a way to improve my *fix*.

Based on what I've read, this revised code does execute without error:

```
 SET @cmd = 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; ' + 
            'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @Table + ' REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = ' + CONVERT(varchar(3), @fillfactor) + ')';
```

My concerns are:

1. Does this change introduce any risk or other danger that is not immediately apparent (just because it runs without errors doesn't settle my nerves!)
2. If not, is there a way to identify exactly what causes this (e.g. a parituclar index or DB column/procedure)?
3. If so, can that be accounted for in the dynamic SQL and more elegantly dealt with?

Thank you in advance for sharing your expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, there is no risk.
2. Catch the error using `TRY / CATCH` block, so you can log the variables' contents somewhere.
3. You can change default connection settings in the server properties so that `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` will always be on. However, it's not a 100% guarantee, since data access drivers can override connection settings (different drivers - ODBC, OLE DB, Native Client, etc. - have slightly different defaults).

Answer (score 2):

Please set the quoted_identifier option to ON then test again

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

Comment: Where abouts should I do this, at the top of the code block?  It's already set in the dynamic code in my *fix* which does run without issue.

Comment: @EvilDr, you could run the SET statement as the first statement in your script instead of in each dynamic statement.

Comment: Yes, using it as the first statement will be safe

Comment: You can also use QUOTENAME() function in dynamic statements surrounding table names, etc.

Comment: this is absolutely true, had the same problem with stored procedures